# react-native: Letters disappear after re-rendering On the current page in react-native

Tags: react-native, letter, viewdiddisappear

It was successful to display the data received through axios after moving the page.
But when it is re-rendered, the letters disappear.
I don't know which one is the problem.

```
const MyPage = ({ navigation, info }) => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      axios
        .get(
          "http://everyweardev-env.eba-azpdvh2m.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/user"
        )
        .then((res) => res)
        .then((data) => {
          setUserInfo(data.data.data.result);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } catch (error) {}
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      getData();
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/*프로필*/}
      <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
        <Image source={require("../../images/profile.png")} />
        <View style={styles.profileName}>
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  marginBottom: hp("1%"),
                  fontSize: wp("7%"),
                }}
              >
                {userInfo?._name} 님
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: wp("5%"),
                }}
              >
                {userInfo?._mail}
              </Text>
```

***After page is moved***

[image]

***After re-rending***
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your case in not `re-rendering` but it `refreshing`.

what's the difference?
`re-rendering` occur after update state.
`refreshing` occur after edit files in your editor.

if your case is really `refreshing` don't worry about it just happened during `development` in debug build, and not happened in release build.

Comment: It means refreshing. If it doesn't happen with the release, I'll just do it.Thank you. I thought it was a problem with the code.